# How to generate a high-frequency clock?

Tags: clock, high-frequency, pll

I want to generate a high frequency (4.25 GHz) clock for a high frequency communication circuit. So, my question is:

What are the alternate ways of generating the high frequency clock and which would be the best way out?

Some pointers to components/ICs would also be of great help.

Comment: Stability specs?

Comment: Is this homework / assignment?

Comment: More detail please.
Is this homework. If so, tell us what is being asked of you and we will help you learn.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon: No, this is not homework. I am designing a high bandwidth (500 MHz) communication circuit around 4.25 GHz central frequency. I am not sure of stability specs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- SAW

  Impatt Diode

  Gunn Diode

  Magnetron / Klystron  / TWT

  Esaki diode (tunnel diode)

  fXo

  Fractional N synthesiser.

  More ...

---

For $US35.70/1 on stock you can gete 1 GHZ fxo modules from Digikey [here](http://search.digikey.com/us/en/products/FXO-PC736-1000/631-1143-ND/1868761) for prices.

FXO-PC73 series. Up to 1.35 MHz. Multiply in various ways from there.
 [Datasheet here](http://www.foxonline.com/pdfs/FXO_PC73.pdf) They say:

- EXTREMELY Low Jitter
- Low Cost
- Frequency Resolution to six decimal places
- Stabilities to ± 20 PPM
- -20 to +70°C or -40 to +85°C operating temperatures
- Serial ID with Comprehensive Traceability

---

For $5/1 you can buy synthesiser ICs that cover your range.
 Typical example only

[Pricing](http://search.digikey.com/us/en/products/LMX2434TM%2FNOPB/LMX2434TM%2FNOPB-ND/567748)
 [Datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lmx2430.pdf) TI LMX2434

---

Gunn diode oscialltyors using cavities for fequency tuning and with varactors for tuning are a time honoured solution and may give you power levels that can be used directly.

[intro](http://www.st-andrews.ac.uk/~jcgl/Scots_Guide/RadCom/part5/page2.html)
 [more intro - good](http://taslimi.ws/cv_files/Gunn_oscillator.pdf)

[ZAX Gunn oscillators](http://www.millimeterwave.com/oscillators.html)
 [Zax catalog - very pretty](http://www.millimeterwave.com/catalog.html)

Gunn XBan - well above your range [useful](http://www.olmicrowaves.com/menucontents/designsupport/rfmicrowave/X-band%20oscillator.pdf)

Ham Radio mag 1980 DIY 10 GHz - very relevant if DIYing [here](http://72.52.208.92/~gbpprorg/mil/cavity/Gunn_Oscillator_Design.pdf)

---

MUCH more.
More detail please.
Is this homework. If so, tell us what is being asked of you and we will help you learn.

Comment: Does the integer-N PLL (which can go upto 64/5) allow locking into any multiples of the oscillator/crystal frequency? or is it just powers of 2 (e.g. 32/33, 64/65, etc)?

Comment: If I use a 50 MHz crystal and a PLL frequency synthesizer like [ADF4108](http://www.analog.com/en/rfif-components/pll-synthesizersvcos/adf4108/products/product.html), can I generate a 4.25 GHz clock?